# How to avoid `.viminfo` in `$HOME`

Tags: vim, vimrc, home-directory

In [one of my setting files](https://github.com/gioele/vim-gioele/blob/master/plugin/xdg_paths.vim#L14) I set `viminfo` to

```
set viminfo+=n~/.cache/vim/info
```

Now *both* `~/.viminfo` and `~/.cache/vim/info` are created. If I deleted `~/.viminfo` it gets recreated again.

How can I tell Vim to avoid creating the `~/.viminfo` file and only use the `~/.cache/vim/info` file?

Comment: Add a symbolic link to point to the intended file and skip the whole setting?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's because Vim already creates the default one before it gets to your redefinition in your `~/.vimrc`. To avoid that, you need to pass this config change directly to Vim on launch:

```
$ vim -i ~/.cache/vim/info
```

Alternatively, clean up inside your `~/.vimrc` via

```
:autocmd VimLeave * call delete('~/.viminfo')
```

Comment: I tried adding a `delete('~/.viminfo')` just after the `set viminfo+=n~~/.cache/...` but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact sequence that Vim uses. Maybe you need to delay the deletion until the end; see my edit. I don't particularly like that unclean alternative, anyway.

Comment: Note: symlinking the viminfo file is not supported, see the recent discussion on [vim-dev](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/D-gkgoJh3Z4/WnERHnAKfEQJ)